# Force Firefox to scale content fitting to the device size

Tags: html, css, firefox

How do I force Firefox (or any other browser) to scale text and images to fit the resolutions of the display?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1; target-density=device-dpi; user-scalable=no; shrink-to-fit=yes">
```

does nothing, sadly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%; width: 95%">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1; target-density=device-dpi; user-scalable=no; shrink-to-fit=yes">
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; width: 95%; padding: 0.313em; word-wrap: break-word">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-5" style="height: 40em; min-width: 25em; border-top: solid; border-bottom: solid; border-color: black; margin:1.250em">
<h3 align="center"> Statistics </h3>

<table class="table" style="width:100%">
<thead style="text-align: left">

<tr>
<td style="border:none"><td>
</tr>
<!-- Repeat a dozen times -->

</thead>
</table>
<div>

<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-5" style="height: 40em; border-top: solid; border-bottom: solid; border-color: black; margin:1.250em">
<img src="diagramm.png"></img>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add firefox specific styling tags?

Comment: The meta viewport element is only part of the equation, do you have responsive CSS and/or media queries for different screen sizes? Share your code and we can give more specific help.

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete and the `<img>` tag is self closing. There is no `</img>`

Comment: Don't use inline css. In your css file you must use media queries for different screen sizes. On the internet you can find a lot of tutorial about that

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark and say your viewport meta is not one you should be using. Do this instead

```
<meta name=viewport content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
```

There is nothing wrong with targeting device dpi and shrink to fit but you have to be very aware of what you are trying to accomplish and what will happen. The meta I show is general purpose that works everywhere.

Comment: Does not work for me with Firefox 72. No scaling there.
This works well for me with Chrome, but also no scaling with FF:
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=540, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=yes">

Comment: @Ralf It's a standard or basic [setting for that tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_basics). You should search for your issue here on SO or open a question so you can show your markup and we can see why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Rob's answer is correct; I wanted to go into a bit more detail, as this took longer than it should to look up and I want to save future readers the time.</sub>

There are two main issues with your `<meta>` element:

1. The list of valid `content` attribute values for `name="viewport"` are:

   - `width`
   - `height`
   - `initial-scale`
   - `minimum-scale`
   - `maximum-scale`
   - `user-scalable`

   Your content has non-standard values, shown in bold:

   `initial-scale=1;`**`target-density=device-dpi;`**`user-scalable=no;`**`shrink-to-fit=yes`**

   **`target-density=device-dpi`** had a very limited implementation when it was in use; I believe only WebKit supported it. WebKit also [deprecated it](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/119527/webkit) and [removed support](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88047) back in 2012. You should not use `target-density=device-dpi` in your code anymore; use the standard `width=device-width`, instead.

   **`shrink-to-fit=yes`** was added to Safari WebKit by Apple for mobile devices in iOS9. It is a non-standard property and never worked on devices other than those running iOS9+ and Safari Mobile. It will likely just be ignored by standards-compliant browsers, so don't feel obligated to remove it if you really want that for iOS devices running Safari Mobile.
2. You are using semi-colon delimiters in your `content` attribute. This is non-standard; only some UAs support this (I believe Safari is the only one currently). You should use commas to delimit your attribute values instead. Frustratingly, this is not mentioned in the HTML W3 spec, but rather in the CSS spec, [CSS Device Adapt](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#viewport-meta):

   > Authors should be using comma in order to ensure content works as expected in all UAs

   I am not sure why the spec authors felt it was appropriate to define HTML data and requirements in a CSS document, but there you have it:

Comment: The viewport meta tag itself is non-standard - though it is a *de facto* standard as far as implementations are concerned. The reason it is heavily referenced in informative prose in css-device-adapt is because the module itself is an attempt at standardizing it in CSS.